# Simplification of $\frac{2\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{35}+5\sqrt{15}-16}{\sqrt7+2\sqrt5-\sqrt3}$

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, irrational-numbers, rationalising-denominator

> Simplify
> $$\dfrac{2\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{35}+5\sqrt{15}-16}{\sqrt7+2\sqrt5-\sqrt3}$$
>
> Final solution should have rational denominators.

Suppose the solution is $X$, I have tried to make up an equation for $X^2$

$$X^2 = \frac{200}{-2\sqrt{15}+2\sqrt{35}-\sqrt{21}+10}$$

My idea is that solving for $X^2$, if can be simply done, can easily give us $X$.

Please help!

Comment: "Final solution should have rational denominators" is a key phase. Consider a simpler problem, like $$\dfrac{2\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{35}+5\sqrt{15}-16}{\sqrt7+\sqrt3}$$How would you make a rational denominator here? How can you make your denominator rational?

Comment: Make use of the formula $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$. You may need to use more than once.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives a minimal polynomial for this number as $$x^4-34x^2+49$$ which means, the number can really be simplified, since this is a bi-quadratic equation, and has a rather simple solution in radicals

Comment: How/why did you create the equation with $X^2$?

Comment: "My idea is that solving for $X^2$, if can be simply done, can easily give us X"

Comment: @Cyh1368 how is that any easier than simply taking the original expression and rationalizing the denominator?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw It's just what I've done, not a good attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: we are generalising the method of rationalising a denominator of two terms. For instance, if our denominator was $\sqrt{a}-b$ then we would multiply (numerator and denominator) by $\sqrt{a}+b$ to get $a-b^2$. That is, we are using "difference of two squares".

Observe that $[(\sqrt{7}+2\sqrt{5})-\sqrt{3}][(\sqrt{7}+2\sqrt{5})+\sqrt{3}]=(\sqrt{7}+2\sqrt{5})^2-(\sqrt{3})^2=7+4\sqrt{35}+20-3$

Now what can we do?

Comment: Doing that would still leave $\sqrt{35}$ at the denominator. How can we deal with that?

Comment: @Cyh1368 how would you have dealt with it if that was the original question?

Comment: @AM I'd use difference of squares to get rid of $\sqrt{35}$. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a shortcut, let $\,a=\sqrt{3}, b=\sqrt{5}, c=\sqrt{7}\,$, then:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
& \dfrac{2\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{35}+5\sqrt{15}-16}{\sqrt{7}+2\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}} = \frac{2ac-bc+5ab-16}{c+2b-a}
\\ &\quad\quad\quad\quad =\frac{c(2a-b)\color{red}{+(2b-a)(2a-b)-(2b-a)(2a-b)}+5ab-16}{c+2b-a}
\\ &\quad\quad\quad\quad = \frac{(c+2b-a)(2a-b)-\cancel{5ab}+2a^2+2b^2+\cancel{5ab}-16}{c+2b-a}
\\ &\quad\quad\quad\quad = 2a-b+\frac{\cancel{6 + 10 - 16}}{c+2b-a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This also follows by polynomial division of $2ac-bc+5ab-16$ by $c+2b-a$, seen as polynomials in $c$. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Polynomialquotienremainder%5B2ac-bc%2B5ab-16%2Cc%2B2b-a%2Cc%5D).

Comment: @lhf Right, that's the polynomial euclidean division except for the label.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is a lot of work to do by hand but at least it does not need any bright ideas for algebraic manipulation.

The problem reduces to finding $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt7+2\sqrt5-\sqrt3}$.

Now, $\theta=\sqrt7+2\sqrt5-\sqrt3$ is a [root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csqrt7%2B2%5Csqrt5-%5Csqrt3) of $x^8 - 120 x^6 + 3632 x^4 - 28800 x^2 + 256$. The extended Euclidean algorithm [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polynomialextendedgcd%5Bx%5E8+-+120+x%5E6+%2B+3632+x%5E4+-+28800+x%5E2+%2B+256%2Cx%2Cx%5D)
$$
1 = \frac{1}{256}(x^8 - 120 x^6 + 3632 x^4 - 28800 x^2 + 256)+ \frac{1}{256}(-x^7 + 120 x^5 - 3632 x^3 + 28800 x)x
$$
Therefore,
$$
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt7+2\sqrt5-\sqrt3} = \frac{1}{\theta} =\frac{1}{256}(-\theta^7 + 120 \theta^5 - 3632 \theta^3 + 28800 \theta)
$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution below can be done by hand without any bright ideas.

We seek a solution of the form
$$
\theta=q_1 + q_2 \sqrt{3} + q_3 \sqrt{5} + q_4 \sqrt{7} +q_5 \sqrt{15} +q_6 \sqrt{21} +q_7 \sqrt{35} + q_8 \sqrt{105}
$$
with $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_8 \in \mathbb Q$.
Then
$$
(2\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{35}+5\sqrt{15}-16)=\theta(\sqrt7+2\sqrt5-\sqrt3)
$$
becomes a sparse linear system in $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_8$, whose [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-3q_2%2B10q_3%2B7q_4%3D-16%2C+%2B10q_5%2B7q_6-q_1%3D0%2C+%2B2q_1-3q_5%2B7q_7%3D0%2C+%2Bq_1-3q_6%2B10q_7%3D0%2C+-q_3%2B2q_2%2B7q_8%3D5%2C+%2Bq_2-q_4%2B10q_8%3D2%2C+%2Bq_5-q_7%2B2q_6%3D0%2C+%2B2q_4-3q_8%2Bq_3%3D-1) is
$$
q_1 = 0, q_2 = 2, q_3 = -1, q_4 = 0, q_5 = 0, q_6 = 0, q_7 = 0, q_8 = 0
$$

The main point here is that this problem lives in the field $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ and that $1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{15},\sqrt{21},\sqrt{35},\sqrt{105}$ is a basis for $K$ over $\mathbb Q$.

If you don't know this bit of field theory, you can still use this solution because the $\theta$ above works.